# Подскажите порядок вывода кластеров на карту когда двигается камера

Tags: android, cluster

Подскажите порядок вывода кластеров на карту, когда двигается камера.

Где и когда нужно прописывать?

Пробую по-разному, но нет вывода кластеров

Comment: Непонятно о чем вопрос, дайте больше деталей

Comment: Получилось отобразить вызвав mClusterManager.cluster();